# Can a mysql database table contain more than 120 columns

Tags: mysql

What are problems occur when mysql server table contains more than 120 columns ?

Comment: What makes you think that's a problem? Read [Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html) and see if you have questions after that.

Comment: Better breakdown the columns into other tables and relate them with foreign keys.

Comment: If there any problem will occurs when table contains more than 120 columns while accessing huge amount of data on table

Comment: Mr. Bimal Kumar why I need to breakdown the columns into another table?

Comment: You haven't said whether this is an oltp or olap database. 120 would be unusual in an oltp database after a normalization process, but might be reasonable in an olap database after a  de-normalization process,

Comment: Other than the phyisical limits partially described below, there are no problems that might occur on a properly normalised data set, if that data set requires in excess of 120 columns. That said, such a table would be a little unusual, and can be symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 1):

from a technical point of view without any consideration on the reasons for which you need 120 columns in a table mysql documentation 5.7 says:

> **Column Count Limits**
>
> MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective
>   maximum may be less for a given table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice to have 120 columns in a table better to split into multiple tables.

**Since MYSQL is famous for relation database, So make relation based tables structure.**

List of issues comes once your application become bigger.

1. Application gets slow (Since data fetching from table is slowly).
2. If your internet is slow, then you may not load the application page.
3. If huge amount of data is loaded at once due to the numbers of columns, then your server require more bandwidth.
4. Might you may not able you open in mobile, Since mobile better work with small amount of data.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/too-many-columns-in-mysql

```
There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table. The exact limit depends on several interacting factors.

Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. Storage engines may place additional constraints on this limit, reducing the effective maximum row size.

The maximum row size constrains the number (and possibly size) of columns because the total length of all columns cannot exceed this size.

...

Individual storage engines might impose additional restrictions that limit table column count. Examples:

InnoDB permits up to 1000 columns.
```

Comment: I would challenge the notion that it's always bad practice - it may be best to have it this way.